# In clojure, how to create a list applying 2 different functions on a collection of 2-elements vectors?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, I have a collection `coll` of 2-elements vectors. I would like to create the collection obtained by applying `f` and `g` on the first and second elements on every vector of the collection, respectively. I think this is related to the [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) construct.

```
(def coll [[1 1000] [2 2000] [3 3000]])
```

IS there an idiomatic way for creating the following result?

```
 [[f(1) g(1000)] [f(2) g(2000)] [f(3) g(3000)]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Again, list comprehension FTW:

```
(vec (for [[x y] [[1 1000] [2 2000] [3 3000]]] [(f x) (g y)]))
```

Comment: +1 for elegance.... always surprising how useful list comprehensions are! Note that in a lot of cases, you don't even need the `vec`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,

```
(vec (map (fn [[p1 p2]] [(f p1) (g p2)])
          [[1 1000] [2 2000] [3 3000]]))
```

Comment: This is what I did. But somehow I have the feeling that there exists a more idiomatic way of writing id. The `fn [[p1 p2]] [(f p1) (g p2)])` part is very hard to read!

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit, I don't think it's hard to read at all, think that as two parts, args vector with destructuring `[[p1 p2]]` and body `[(f p1) (g p2)]`. Maybe you could find it more readable if you split this two parts with a newline.

Comment: What do you think of @skuro's answer with List Comprehension?

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit, I generally prefer `map`s and `filter`s over list comprehensions but it's mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: Why do you prefer `map`s over list comprehension?

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit I guess it's a matter of mental models, which could even depend on the problem at hand: `map` is all about transforming a seq, while list comprehension is about generating a seq.

Comment: it also seems to me that the solution using `for` is roughly 3x slower than the `map` version. Don't know why yet.

Answer (score 1):

To write this from scratch, I would do exactly what skuro did - it's simple, easy, and readable. But I also wrote a higher-order function to abstract this some time ago, named [knit](https://github.com/flatland/useful/blob/develop/src/useful/fn.clj#L90). So now I would write this as

```
(map (knit f g) [[1 1000] [2 2000] [3 3000]])
```